# Is there a way to toggle the "use audio port for" preference with apple script on mac book pro

Tags: audio, applescript, toggle, preferences

i wonder if there is a way to change the "use audio port for" setting on the sound preference pane in mac os x. this is a feature, which allows mac book pro users to use their audio jack for sound out- or input.

it's quite a bit annoying, if you always have to open the system preferences and navigate to the sound pane.

I've already tried by myself, but I ain't got any "results". I guess the most desired scripting technology should be "Apple Script" to perform this task.
I'm completly new to apple script.

Is there anybody which have a solution in mind? I stuck at the point of obtaining the name of this preference id.

I couldn't find any helpful information regarding this problem so far.

Thanks for any help.

N.

Comment: Some more recent MBPs use a 4-pin 3.5mm jack. I used a 4-pin to 3-pin input/output splitter so I never have to switch, and can use both at the same time. Here's an example: http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-MUYHSMFF-Headset-Splitter-Adapter/dp/B004SP0WAQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-click the volume icon in your menubar. There you can select to use the port for output or input.